# How to unlink all posts from tracking same amount of views

Tags: php, loop, views

I'm trying to show the top 5 most popular ( most viewed ) blogs. It is working as it should and then I added a script in the `functions.php` to display the views just while I build this so I can see it's working.

The problem is when I click a post, they all +1 in views, even tho they are ordering my most viewed to least viewed as they should, they are still connected to each other. How do I get them to ++ independently and not be connected?

functions.php

```
  /* most popular script to count the posts */

    function getPostViews($postID){
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
            return "0 View";
        }
        return $count.' Views';
    }

    /* the script to display the view count */

    function bac_PostViews($postID) {

        //Set the name of the Posts Custom Field.
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';

        //Returns values of the custom field with the specified key from the specified post.
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);

        //If the the Post Custom Field value is empty.
        if($count == ''){
            $count = 0; // set the counter to zero.

            //Delete all custom fields with the specified key from the specified post.
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);

            //Add a custom (meta) field (Name/value)to the specified post.
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
            return $count . ' View';

        //If the the Post Custom Field value is NOT empty.
        }else{
            $count++; //increment the counter by 1.
            //Update the value of an existing meta key (custom field) for the specified post.
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);

            //If statement, is just to have the singular form 'View' for the value '1'
            if($count == '1'){
            return $count . ' View';
            }
            //In all other cases return (count) Views
            else {
            return $count . ' Views';
            }
        }
    }
```

the loop

```
 <?php $catquery = new WP_Query(array(
          'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
          'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
          'posts_per_page' => 5,
          'cat' => '52',

        )); ?>

      <ol class="topheadlines">
      <?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
        <!-- display view count --> 
        <?php if(function_exists('bac_PostViews')) {
            echo bac_PostViews(get_the_ID());
        }?>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;">
          <li class="topheadlines-text"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 topheadline-thumb" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">
          <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large' ); ?>
        </div>
      </div>

      <?php endwhile;
          wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>
```

single.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @package understrap
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header();
$container = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
?>


  <div class="row" style="margin:0;">
    <div class="col-md-9 single-bg" style="padding:0;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="single-wrap">

                <h5 class="single-date">
                    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                </h5>

                <h2 class="single-title">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h2>

                <h3 class="single-sub-title">
                    <?php echo the_field('mt_post_subtitle'); ?>
                </h3>

                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="single-thumb">

        <?php $category = get_the_category();
          $firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;
        ?>

        <?php if($firstCategory != 'Daily (Email)') { ?>
             <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large' );

          }
        ?>

                </div>

                <div class="single-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>

                  <?php
                    $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
                    $author_badge = get_field('author_badge', 'user_'. $author_id );
                    ?>

                <div class="author-wrap clearfix">
                    <div class="author-pic">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author() ); ?>">
                        <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 50 ); ?>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="author-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author() ); ?>">
                        <?php the_author(); ?><br><span class="author-title"><?php the_field('title', 'user_'. $author_id ); ?>, The Hustle</span>
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div><!-- end author wrap -->



                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php $category = get_the_category();
                    $firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;
                ?>


                <?php if($firstCategory == 'Daily (Email)') { ?>
                    <a href="/daily">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <?php if($firstCategory == 'Stories') { ?>
                    <a href="/stories">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>

                <?php if($firstCategory == 'Blog') { ?>
                    <a href="/blog">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>

                <?php if($firstCategory == 'Episodes') { ?>
                    <a href="/">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <?php if($firstCategory == '') { ?>
                    <a href="/">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <?php if($firstCategory == 'Uncategorized') { ?>
                    <a href="/">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
        <?php if($firstCategory == 'Brief') { ?>
          <a href="/series/brief">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
          </a>
          <?php
          }
        ?>

            <div class="recent-wrap">
                <h4 class="featured-headlines">
                  Recent Posts
                </h4>
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[recent_post_carousel design="design-1" category="52,6"]'); ?>

            </div><!-- end recent wrap -->

            </div><!-- end singlewrap -->

        </div><!-- end container fluid -->
    </div><!-- end col 9 -->
    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0; margin:0;">
      <?php include get_template_directory() . '/inc/page-sidebar.php'; ?>
    </div><!-- end col 3 sidebar -->
  </div> <!-- end master row -->


<?php get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the loop:

```
getPostViews(get_the_ID());
```

instead of:

```
bac_PostViews(get_the_ID());
```

So your loop should be like this:

```
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query(array(
          'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
          'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
          'posts_per_page' => 5,
          'cat' => '52',

        )); ?>

      <ol class="topheadlines">
      <?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
        <!-- display view count --> 
        <?php if(function_exists('getPostViews')) {
            echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
        }?>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;">
          <li class="topheadlines-text"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 topheadline-thumb" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">
          <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large' ); ?>
        </div>
      </div>

      <?php endwhile;
          wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>
```

And in single.php you must call bac_PostViews function:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @package understrap
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header();
$container = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
?>


  <div class="row" style="margin:0;">
    <div class="col-md-9 single-bg" style="padding:0;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="single-wrap">

                <h5 class="single-date">
                    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                </h5>

                <h2 class="single-title">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h2>

                <h3 class="single-sub-title">
                    <?php echo the_field('mt_post_subtitle'); ?>
                </h3>

                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="single-thumb">

        <?php if(function_exists('bac_PostViews')) {
            echo bac_PostViews(get_the_ID());
        }?>

        <?php $category = get_the_category();
          $firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;
        ?>

        <?php if($firstCategory != 'Daily (Email)') { ?>
             <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large' );

          }
        ?>

                </div>

                <div class="single-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>

                  <?php
                    $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
                    $author_badge = get_field('author_badge', 'user_'. $author_id );
                    ?>

                <div class="author-wrap clearfix">
                    <div class="author-pic">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author() ); ?>">
                        <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 50 ); ?>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="author-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author() ); ?>">
                        <?php the_author(); ?><br><span class="author-title"><?php the_field('title', 'user_'. $author_id ); ?>, The Hustle</span>
                    </a>
                    </h5>
                </div><!-- end author wrap -->



                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php $category = get_the_category();
                    $firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;
                ?>


                <?php if($firstCategory == 'Daily (Email)') { ?>
                    <a href="/daily">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <?php if($firstCategory == 'Stories') { ?>
                    <a href="/stories">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>

                <?php if($firstCategory == 'Blog') { ?>
                    <a href="/blog">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>

                <?php if($firstCategory == 'Episodes') { ?>
                    <a href="/">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <?php if($firstCategory == '') { ?>
                    <a href="/">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <?php if($firstCategory == 'Uncategorized') { ?>
                    <a href="/">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
        <?php if($firstCategory == 'Brief') { ?>
          <a href="/series/brief">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary single-read-more"><?php echo $button_text; ?>Related Posts</button>
          </a>
          <?php
          }
        ?>

            <div class="recent-wrap">
                <h4 class="featured-headlines">
                  Recent Posts
                </h4>
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[recent_post_carousel design="design-1" category="52,6"]'); ?>

            </div><!-- end recent wrap -->

            </div><!-- end singlewrap -->

        </div><!-- end container fluid -->
    </div><!-- end col 9 -->
    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0; margin:0;">
      <?php include get_template_directory() . '/inc/page-sidebar.php'; ?>
    </div><!-- end col 3 sidebar -->
  </div> <!-- end master row -->


<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: It shows the correct order of most popular down to least, but now it's not counting at all. So when I click into the blog the counter doesn't change. This is an issue with the counter function?

Comment: The counter function should only be used in the single page not in the loop.

Comment: That's what I mean, when I click into a single.php it's not counting as my function is set up to do.  function getPostViews($postID){
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
            return "0 View";
        }
        return $count.' Views';
    }

Comment: Edit your question and add single.php code so i can see it.

Comment: ok I added single.php. many thanks.

Comment: @RLM add bac_PostViews function to your single.php file.